# Making a page secure

Tags: asp.net

I am building a ASP.NET website that has members pages. I have created a folder where I keep the members pages in and that can only be accessed by logging in or creating a new account. The problem is how do I make the url of these members pages secure, so that someone cant simply give the url to another user for them to copy into a browser or bookmark. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the Authentication element in your web.config.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871 has details on this but roughly you will add things that look like this:

```
    <location path="subdir1">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" /> 
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
```

This will deny access to that subdir to all anonymous users.

To quote the MSDN page above:

> When using forms-based authentication
>   in ASP.NET applications, only
>   authenticated users are granted access
>   to pages in the application.
>   Unauthenticated users are
>   automatically redirected to the page
>   specified by the loginUrl attribute of
>   the Web.config file where they can
>   submit their credentials. In some
>   cases, you may want to permit users to
>   access certain pages in an application
>   without requiring authentication.

---

**Edit:**

In response to your edit of testing user pages then there are two ways I can think of that this might work. If the page is specific to a given user then you can just make sure that in the code rather than getting the user details from the url that you look up who the logged in user is and give them their page. So for example if you are currently looking at members/mypage.aspx?user=bob then instead just link to members/mypage.aspx and in the code get the name of the logged in user to use. Then there is no way to tell the code that you want Bob's page without being Bob.

In the more likely event that you have groups of users (eg admin) that can see a page then you will need to put some code on your page to check permissions. For a given page you will need to work out who can view it somehow (eg by lookign up that page against the allowed user roles to get a list of roles) and then check if the logged in user is in that list of who can view (does the user have one of those roles.

eg Bob is an admin and Frank isn't. When going to your admin.aspx page you first of all lookup admin.aspx and find out that roles Admin and SuperAdmin are allowed to view it. You then look up the logged in user and iterate through their roles til you find one in the allowed roles list. If you find one process the page as normal, if you don't then either redirect somewhere else or throw an exception (eg throw your own MyAccessDeniedException that gets caught in your global event handler and shows a message explaining the user doesn't have permissions).

All of this can be done in a base class of your page to prevent you having to include the code on every page. That is you can create MyPage that inherits from Page and in the onload (or oninit or wherever you fancy) of MyPage run this security check. Then all the pages of your site inherit from MyPage instead of Page and you immediately get the functionality on all pages.

Hopefully this answers your questions.

Comment: How to prevent when user (A) looks at secured page of user (B) - both are permitted per your rule, but B can look at A

Comment: I just noticed in my rep page that I got a -1 (and a +1) for this response... Why the -1 since even the original answer seemed to me to answer the question as stated...

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to give that, my mistake im new to the site

Comment: @pmoth81: 'sok, now I've edited the post you can undo it if you want by either clicking the down arrow again (I think) or by clicking the up arrow to give me a +1 instead. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but is there any bit of code that prevents the url of a secure page from being copied into another browser?

Comment: @pmoth81: You can't prevent the copying of a url. All you can do is stop the url being sensitive data. Can you give an example of your url and explain which bit is the sensitive bit and what it is doing? (obviously only an example is needed, I'm not asking for secure urls. ;-) )

Comment: I know you cant stop the copying of a url. What I want to konw is that if a user has access to a members page, what happens if he gives the url of this page to another user so they wont have to join to view that page, they can simply copy the url into their browser.

Comment: @pmoth81: If you are worried about users who haven't joined then my original answer tells you how to deny access to anonymous users. If this isn't answering the question then I'm not understanding what you are trying to do properly... Maybe edit your question with a more verbose example of how your security is bypassable at the moment and why suggested fixes won't actually work.

Comment: OK I'll try and be more verbose. My website which has been created using ASP.NET has pages which are visible to all users and certain pages which are only available to members who have created an account. These members pages are kept in a separate folder. In the ASP.NET Configuration settings I have set the access rules ensure that only logged in users can access these pages. (continued below)

Comment: What I want to know now is how secure these pages will be. For instance if I copy a url of a members page and email it to someone else, and they put this into their browser, would it take them to that secure page or would it take them to the login screen?

Comment: It looks very much like the link I put at the beginning of my answer would have answered that question. I have edited my answer to directly quote the relevant section now. In essence though if a user tries to access a page they haven't got permission for it would take them to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

In web.config you need specify that this folder for permitted user only.

To grant individual security (person against person) just add checking (for example at Page_Load) that member is permitted to see this page and throw HttException with code 403 (forbidden)

Comment: I have that working but I want to make the url secure so that a user cannot simply copy the secure page url into another browser

Comment: @pmoth81 - the url can be visible by many participants, but the developer should grant that only permitted can have access to it.
Even if you put many forces to avoid copying url, what prevent me just copy My url and change it to another one. For example: http://yourwerb/secured/user-dewfy - anytime can be changed manually  http://yourwerb/secured/user-pmoth81

Comment: OK I'll try and be more verbose. My website which has been created using ASP.NET has pages which are visible to all users and certain pages which are only available to members who have created an account. These members pages are kept in a separate folder. 
In the ASP.NET Configuration settings I have set the access rules ensure that only logged in users can access these pages.
(continued below)

Comment: What I want to know now is how secure these pages will be. For instance if I copy a url of a members page and email it to someone else, and they put this into their browser, would it take them to that secure page or would it take them to the login screen?

Comment: ** For instance if I copy a url of a members page and email it to someone else, and they put this into their browser, would it take them to that secure page or would it take them to the login screen? **  - yes, declared in web.config rule of restriction grants that only logged in user can see it. And user will be redirected to login  page specified (for example) by form-auth. On other hand (see my comment about user A and B) cannot be distinguished by web.config (since they both logged in). That is why you have to provide additional check in Page_Load